# Why does an answer on a migrated question show "deleted by owner X hours ago" when most other questions simply say "deleted X hours ago"?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

After I cast the 5th vote to close on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788521/eclipse-crashed?noredirect=1) question, I saw that two of the answers were marked "deleted by **owner** X secs/mins/hrs ago" whereas all the other migrated questions that I've seen simply say "deleted X secs/mins/hrs ago" ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795796/ubuntu-11-04-not-showing-in-the-grub-boot-loader?noredirect=1)) without mentioning by whom. Here's a screenshot of the first question for those who can't view the deleted answers:

[image]

This is not a major issue, but I'm curious if these deletions are really attributed to the owner and if it will count against them (serial deleted answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an answer is deleted by the original author, or a moderator, it will list the username and the time of nuking. (It will list the Community user if it was flagged as spam or offensive)

> deleted by {username} {timestamp}

When you don't see a username it's because the question itself was deleted or migrated. In those cases you'll get the other version on the answer:

> deleted {timestamp}

Users can delete their answer before the question vanishes. In which case, you'll see who deleted the post.

Any answers deleted before a question is migrated will **not** be shifted with the rest of the answers to the new site.

In those cases, the bus has left them at the camp and they're stranded while all the other kids are riding back home.

Comment: No, this is not the case. All three answers have the same timestamp (incredible coincidence if the user deleted at the same time!), two of them say "deleted by owner" and one of them is present on SU. You can see the full screenshots in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99521/why-are-some-of-the-answers-on-a-migrated-question-not-present-on-the-target-site) that I just asked.

Comment: Also, the users in question haven't logged-in in the past 5-6 hours. [Psy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/321366/psy) and [ascanio](http://stackoverflow.com/users/518652/ascanio)

Comment: Well that's a might puzzler there then

Answer (score 0):

The question was migrated.

These causes it and the answers to be automatically deleted by the system, after some time has passed.

No user deleted them - an automated process did, hence no name. The items *with* a name just mean that they were deleted prior to migration.