# Why are some of the answers on a migrated question not present on the target site?

Tags: support, status-completed, answers, migration

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788521/eclipse-crashed?noredirect=1) was recently migrated to SU. The original question on SO has 3 answers on it, whereas the migrated question on SU has only 2 answers (screenshots follow the question). Although I can't see any deleted questions on SU, I confirmed with [random](https://superuser.com/users/307/random) a mod on SU that there are no other answers on the question.

Why did the answer by Psy not get migrated to SU?

**Note:** The user [hasn't logged in in the past 5 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3kTO.png) as of writing this post, so he couldn't have deleted it himself.

#### SO screenshot:

[image]

#### SU screenshot:

[image]

```
---------- End of screenshots ----------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was in fact deleted by Psy before it was migrated:

[image: going going gone]

The same holds true for the answer posted by ascanio - however his answer was undeleted prior to the migration.

[image]

Comment: 10k's should still be able to see that in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6788713/revisions) too.  Unfortunately the links aren't available unless an edit is made (or you know the urls).

Comment: @yoda I updated the answer - ascano undeleted his answer prior to the migration

Comment: @Geoff: Thanks! Much appreciated.